# Testing for NULL vs. length of string pointer x86 vs x64?

Tags: c, windows, 64-bit

This is the only way to test if the return string is empty. Each fails in the other's architecture. The question is why? Why does `!=NULL` fail on x86 and `_tcslen(*sDateOut)>0` fail on x64?:

```
BOOL FormatDate(TCHAR *sIn, TCHAR **sOut) {
free(*sOut);*sOut=NULL; // Clear

...
if (condition1)
    *sOut = calloc(length,sizeof(TCHAR);
...

#ifdef WIN64
    return (*sOut != NULL);
#else
    return (_tcslen(*sOut)>0);
#endif
}
```

Comment: The real question is why does `_tcslen` fail on WIN64?

Comment: I guess what is hidden behind the `...` is important to answer this question.

Comment: Only important insofar that a calloc *may* or *may not* happen. That is what I am trying to test for. I could set a BOOL, but that's not too elegant, esp with it potentially being set many times.

Comment: Is there a chance you don't allocate place for the null terminator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to check for an empty string you should compare the first character with `'\0'`, **not** `NULL`.

The reason for this is because `NULL` is supposed to represent a null pointer - it's actual value may not actually be zero.

---

Now back to the example, if you want to test if `TCHAR **sOut` is a valid pointer to an empty string this test should work:

```
if (sOut && *sOut && (*sOut)[0] != _T('\0')) {
    // non-empty
} else {
    // empty or invalid pointer
}
```

Comment: What is each one of those testing?

Comment: JeffR: `sOut` check whether or not it is a NULL pointer, `*sOut` does the same but then for the string and `(*sOut)[0] != _T('\0')` checks whether or not the first character is a null character (implying an empty string).

Comment: -1 for the confusion about NULL's actual value not actually being zero. The typical definition of `NULL` is `(void *) 0`, it's up to the compiler to implement the exact bit-pattern, but in source it's an integral constant with the value 0. See http://c-faq.com/null/null2.html.

Comment: @unwind: yes, but he's using it to check for a __null byte__ in a string, which could lead to issues.

Comment: @unwind: In C, `NULL` is not required to be an integral constant with value `0`. As you say yourself, it's also allowed to be such a thing cast to `void*`, for example `((void*)0)`. It's true that it's irrelevant whether NULL's actual value is actually zero, nightcracker was talking about whether or not it compares equal to a zero byte: and if it has type `void*` then it can't be compared at all. But anyway, the questioner's code *doesn't* compare `NULL` to the first character of anything, so I'm not sure why that warning was needed in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, both do quite different thing:

```
(*sOut != NULL)
```

is true whenever `sOut` points to a valid pointer to `char`. It doesn't mean the string it points to has zero length, but rather that there isn't any string.

```
(_tcslen(*sOut)>0)
```

on the other hand, actually checks the length of the string `*sOut` points to, and assumes there is one.

So you should combine the checks to ensure `*sOut` is a non-zero length null-terminated string:

```
(*sOut != NULL) && (_tcslen(*sOut)>0)
```

Note that the signature of your function looks like it is supposed to *put* something into `sOut`, so testing for zero length string there doesn't make sense to me. I guess you know what you are doing.

Comment: I can't combine them, because '(*sOut != NULL)' fails on x86 and '(_tcslen(*sOut)>0)' fails on x64.

Comment: @JeffR: And what do you mean by "fail"? What does it do that you think it shouldn't, or what doesn't it do that you think it should?

Comment: by 'fail', I mean I get a memory exception.

Answer (score 1):

sOut is of type `TCHAR **`, so *sOut is a pointer, not a character.

The two tests are checking for different things:

```
*sOut != NULL; // is the pointer NULL?

_tcslen(*sOut)>0; // does the pointer point to a zero-length string? (presumes pointer is non-NULL!)
```

Why you would check for two different things in WIN64 vs. other is not clear from this sample.

Comment: I only had to check because one line fails on x86 and the other fails on x64.

Answer (score 0):

What is "empty string" for you?
Null-Pointer and zero-sized string is a different thing. Pointer to zero-sized string is not NULL.
Correct code must check both situation:

> ((*sOut !=NULL) && (_tcslen(*sOut)>0))

Comment: Yes, but one or the other fails on x86 and x64.